# Main form and subform for 1:m tables in Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, vba, subform

I want to display the fields from two tables on a form. The two tables are ‘Customer’ and ‘Vehicle’. (1:m). The customer fields will be displayed in the main form and to display the Vehicle fields I have put a subform in Datasheet view and I added a textbox for vehicleID.  When I enter CustomerID and click a commandbutton on another form this main form (frmCustomerDetails) will be opened with the subform (sfrmVehicle).
The customer fields are correctly displayed in the main form. There is no error messages, but I cant see the Vehicle fields in the subform. It just displays #Name? six times. There are six records in the vehicle table, so I think it doesn’t even filter the vehicleid for this customer. (Only two records in the vehicle table belong to this customer.)
My Ms Access 2013 VBA code is;

```
Dim strSQL1 As String
Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset
strSQL1 = "SELECT Customer.CustomerID, " & _
               "  Customer.fName, " & _
               "  Customer.lName, " & _
               "  Customer.Telephone, " & _
               "  Customer.MobilePhone, " & _
               "  Customer.EMail, " & _
               "  Customer.Address1, " & _
               "  Customer.Address2, " & _
               "  Customer.City, " & _
               "  Customer.State, " & _
               "  Customer.PostalCode, " & _
               "  Vehicle.VehicleID " & _
               "FROM Customer INNER JOIN Vehicle ON Customer.CustomerID = Vehicle.CustomerID;"
Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(Name:=strSQL1, Type:=dbOpenDynaset)
rs1.FindFirst "[CustomerID] =""" & txtIDs & """"
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmCustomerDetails"
[Forms]![frmCustomerDetails]![txtCustomerName] = rs1.Fields!fName
..
..
[Forms]![frmCustomerDetails]![sfrmVehicle]![txtVehicleId].ControlSource = rs1.Fields!VehicleID
rs1.Close
Set rs1 = Nothing
```

Do I have to have two different SQL statements for main form and subform? Then how to do filtering. Need help. please.

Comment: You don't need any code at all for a main form + subform. Please read: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-form-that-contains-a-subform-a-one-to-many-form-ddf3822f-8aba-49cb-831a-1e74d6f5f06b

Answer (score 0):

To do the filtering on the subform all you need is this code;

```
Me.sfrmVehicle.Form.Filter = "[vehicleID]=" & Me.vehicleIDTextBox
Me.sfrmVehicle.Form.FilterOn = True
```

And for the name error in the subform, that could be because you haven't selected the correct source object in the data tab in its property sheet.

**Edit:** With the SQL statements, like Andre said, you don't need them.

Comment: Thank you Andre and Mark. My another requirement is little bit complicated thats why Im trying it with VBA code and SQL statement. Next I have to display the fields from 3 tables in a form. when a user enter Vehicle ID, the customer fields from tblcustomer, vehicle data from tblVehicle and pass data from tblPass have to be displayed. tblcustomer, tblvehicl 1:m and tblvehicle and tblPass 1:m. Mark I have already selected the correct source object i dont know the cause of this error.

Comment: Is there a small green triangle in the top left corner of the textboxes displaying #Name when view the subform in design view? If so then your spelling of the control source in the textboxes are incorrect and cannot be found in the control source of the subform.

Comment: There is no green triangle and the spelling is correct. I just deleted the .controlsource to set the value property like this and checked;
[Forms]![frmCustomerDetails]![sfrmVehicle]![txtVehicleId] = rs1.Fields!VehicleID
Then only one Vehicle ID (QWE0123) was displayed seven times. QWE0123 is a field of the first record in the vehicle table.